# Unable to configure Rest Api as a linked service in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Hello i am trying to add this rest api as a linked service because I want to upload files to it.

But i am unable to configure it as a linked service.

My question how should I configure this in azure data factory?

Here under you will see a example that I got from the api documentation:

POST https://use4-mdm.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/rdm-service/external/v1/import
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm
IDS-SESSION-ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=import-code-values.csv

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=importSettings
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
"delimiter":"COMMA",
"textQualifier":"DOUBLE_QUOTE",
"codepage":"UTF8",
"dateFormat":"ISO",
"containerType":"CODELIST",
"containerId":"9ab3201990a54dcdc86f54cf",
"startingRow":null
}

Comment: can you please share exactly what error you are getting while creating linked service?

Comment: check this link out: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/how-to-send-dataset-dynamically-to-a-rest-service-using-adf/ba-p/3587555

Answer (score 0):

As you want to add this REST API as a linked service because you want to upload files to it. you have to add it in sink.

First open your datafactory instance.

> **Go to Managed >> Linked Service >> New >> Rest and click on continue**

[image]

Give **name to linked service**, **select integration runtime** or it will be generated automatically, **give base URL** for connector and **select appropriate authentication** and t**est your connection** and click on `create`.

[image]

After this in your activity in sink under sink dataset select this linked service and in request method select as `POST`.

[image]